# Download QA band of Landsat 1-8

Tags: landsat, download, data-quality

In one of my work, I just need the QA band of Landsat, but USGS Earth Explorer does not provide band by band data download opportunity. As I am interested to get all the available Landsat QA data from Landsat 1 through 8, downloading full scene(all bands) will be useless for me.

I have tried SCP plugin with QGIS, did not found any solution.

Is there any way I could download only QA band and the metadata rather than downloading the whole scene?